# How to deal with an attack on registration-form?

Tags: security, email, registration

Question on registration process

I was thinking about email verification, and was playing with some app. 
What if

-) an attacker write a script that register millions account with different random email address(all existing, people's email)Then when the people register, it will prompt email already exists in db?

-) Or even simpler, what if a user register with someone else's email address? The registration Ajax triggers a creation of userid and info into the user table in the DB, but the verification is not done.

But then, when the "real" user with the email register, the email is already taken...?As there can not be 2 email address exist in the db at the same time(As the script won't be able to distinguish between the users....

Comment: So why don't you verify the email addresses that they belong to the person who registered them?

Comment: Related: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/47748/8340

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you should try to detect if the same IP sends you multiple registration requests during a short period of time and blacklist it (at least for a while).

Second, even when the verification email is sent - you can do many things to avoid "duplicate registration" problem, here are a few examples:

1. Run a cleanup job once a day - deleting all the entries of users that didn't verify their account (via the email) for more than 24 hours
2. Do not create the user account until the user verified his/her registration (you can create an entry in another table: UNVERIFIED_USERS for instance). By doing this - you make sure to reduce latencies for existing users when such an attack occurs - since the USERS table will not be modified.
3. If a user tried to register and he/she already "has an account" you should allow the user to reset the password by sending another verification email with a link to do it.
4. You can use solutions like [captcha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) in the registration form - to prevent such attacks. Today there are smart bots that can by-pass captcha, so you can also look for [captcha-alternatives](https://www.google.com/search?q=captcha-alternatives&oq=captcha-alternatives&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.508j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Thanks for the info/advice!! I am thinking to incorporate an easy to "register" process for an App, like the ones that you just enter email and password and it registers straight away and then you can verify later, and still capture info for you. I was just thinking, if it is ok, if someone registered my email address, and (like your point 3) allows to send an "override" verification email to my email address,(because i have to login to my email account,so it verifies its me) then i can override that account?

Comment: @John yes, that's the idea - to allow the user to re-verify.

Comment: And i guess i can store/record, how many accounts registered per device, and limits that

Comment: @John that's also a good idea! as I wrote - there are many ways to make it more secure: start with the easy-to-implement ones and if you feel like you need an additional protection start implementing the more-complicated options.

Comment: Thanks so much! Yer, i forgot, because i could always pull the UUID, and UUID is always unique, but IP i can always VPN it. But i guess if they VPN it, the UUID will be different too. But i will stick with your option 3 for now.